# перевести в JSON

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlite3, микросервисы

Мне нужно добавить имя пользоваеля и пароль и получить ответ в  формате JSON.
**Вот так: ID:[1]**
Тестирую через Insomnia, **{"username":"veronika", "password":"12345" , "admin_password":"m1234"}** когда жму SEND, то username и password добавляется в бд,
но происходит ошибка 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR и Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8
а в терминале Visual Code получаю ошибку **'list index out of range'**. Вообщем есть функции login, delete user они работают, поэтому вырезала  их из кода,

У меня есь файл **dal.py**, там все, что касается SQL:

```
import sqlite3
from flask import flash

admin_password='m1234'

class DAL():
   filename='users.db'
   def __init__(self) -> None:    
    self.initialize()

    def exec(self,SQL):
       rows=[]
       with sqlite3.connect(self.filename) as con:
         cur=con.cursor()
         cur.execute(SQL)
         rows=cur.fetchall()
         con.commit()
       return rows

   def initialize(self):
   self.exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ( "username" TEXT, "password" TEXT)')

    def add(self,username,password,admin_password):
    rows=[]
    if admin_password=='m1234':
        rows=self.exec(f'SELECT rowid,username,password FROM users WHERE username="{username}" and password="{password}"')            
        if len(rows)==0: 
            self.exec(f'INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ("{username}","{password}")')
            id=rows[0][0]                
        else: 
            id="add user failed"
    return id
```

class User:

```
def__init__(self,username="None",password="None",admin_password="None",id="None",password_reg="None",email="None") -> None:
    self.username=username
    self.password=password
    self.id=id
    self.admin_password=admin_password
    self.password_reg=password_reg
    self.email=email


def save(self):
    self.id=DAL().add(self.username,self.password,self.admin_password)
    return self.id
```

и файл **Login.py**

```
from flask import Flask,Response,request,flash
import json
import sqlite3

from db.dal import DAL,User
app = Flask(__name__)

con=sqlite3.connect('users.db')
cur=con.cursor()



@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    username=request.json["username"]
    password=request.json["password"]
    admin_password=request.json["admin_password"]
    user=User(username,password,admin_password)
    user.authenticate()
    user.save()
    id=user.id
    r=Response(json.dumps({'id':id})) # add user id to JSON
    r.headers["Content-Type"]="application/json"

    return r
```

Ну и вот собственно ошибка:

```
  File "C:\Users\veronika\Desktop\login-service\login.py", line 32, in 
  add_user
  user.save()
  File "C:\Users\veronika\Desktop\login-service\db\dal.py", line 93, in 
  save
  self.id=DAL().add(self.username,self.password,self.admin_password)
  File "C:\Users\veronika\Desktop\login-service\db\dal.py", line 43, in 
  add
  id=rows[0][0]
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: rows у вас пустой

Comment: Не совсем поняла, А каким он должен быть?

Comment: "А каким он должен быть?" а это вы должны знать. А зачем вам проверка на длину rows? При длине rows равному 0, делать id=rows[0][0] ?

Comment: Можно поподробнее пожалуйста.  Если убираю из rows [0][0], то он возвращает мне id:[  ], т.е пустой

Comment: А зачем вам проверка на длину rows? в частности len(rows)==0? ниже по коду пытаетесь id=rows[0][0]                
ведь len(rows) равен 0 то есть rows [], пустота, не чего нет. Не возможно из пустоты, что либо достать rows[0][0]

Comment: Если длина rows==0, то значит в бд нет такого пользователя и мы его добавляем (INSERT INTO....). Иначе add user failed

Comment: id=rows[0][0]? 'Если длина rows==0' удалите id=rows[0][0].

Comment: Вообще запуталась, вот такую ошибку получаю теперь: File "C:\Users\veronika\Desktop\login-service\login.py", line 32, in add_user
    user.save()
  File "C:\Users\veronika\Desktop\login-service\db\dal.py", line 93, in save
    self.id=DAL().add(self.username,self.password,self.admin_password)
  File "C:\Users\veronika\Desktop\login-service\db\dal.py", line 46, in add
    return id
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'id' referenced before assignment.

Comment: Я же ее обозначила в строке 93: save self.id=DAL().add(self.username,self.password,self.admin_password)

Comment: Если это условие `if admin_password=='m1234':` не сработает, то переменная `id` не будет задана и что вы пытаетесь вернуть тогда через `return id` непонятно. И вы уже путаете переменную `id` и поле класса `self.id`, это **разные** переменные.

Comment: Как раз, когда if admin_password ==m1234 не срабатывает, то все работает норм. Возвращается add failed в формате JSON

Comment: Т.е вы думаете лучше вообще по другому функцию записать ?

Answer (score 0):

смотри, тебе надо несколько вещей поменять в твоей функции def add():
и все будет работать.

```
def add(self,username,password,admin_password):
    id=[]
    if admin_password=='m1234':
        rows=self.exec(f'SELECT rowid,username,password FROM users WHERE username="{username}" and password="{password}"')            
        if len(rows)==0: 
            self.exec(f'INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ("{username}","{password}")')
                     
        else: 
            id="add user failed"
    return id
```

Обьясняю логику:
ровс мы меняем на айди и возвращаем его в конце функции поскольку вначале функции айди = [] , то мы добавляем туда айди только что созданного пользователя